# Multiple mongodb servers seen as one and data flow management

Tags: mongodb, sharding, redundancy

For my application I need to *move old data* periodically from a mongodb server to another one (ie, two distinct servers). I also want to be able to query those data as if they were the *same database*.

In short terms, I want to be able to see two mongodb instances (on two different servers) as one and be able to control when and where the data is stored.

I read about the concept of *sharding* and *chunks* and rapidly saw the [moveChunk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/moveChunk/#dbcmd.moveChunk) function which can easily do what I want.

The problem is that it seems to be impossible to configure such architecture in mongodb. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you read about Replication in MongoDB?

Comment: Yes I've read about it, do you have any replication strategy to suggest ?

Comment: I think what you are trying is easily possible with replication without deletion of data. From your sentence "I need to move old data periodically from one server to another",  "I also want to be able to query those data as if they were the same database" this sentence doesn't make sense. If you are moving data from one to another then you shouldn't be able to access it on first server. If you want to copy/sync data then Mongo Replication should do the trick of same db name across diff machines for you.

Comment: If I ear you well, you propose to do a basic mirror server with no sync on deletion on the primary server ?
If so, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726617/mongodb-replication-without-deleting-data-in-secondary) (from 2014) suggest doing a script that delete and add. I already did this but I though mongodb has a feature to do that "alone".

Comment: Half correct. but Mongo doesn't support custom synchronization. best way is to keep all data. Do you need all data(included deleted data on primary) on another server for analytics purpose?

Comment: Not exactly, I need to keep all data (including those deleted on the primary) on a secondary server for analytics and keep the primary for fresh new data (without the deleted one).

Answer (score 1):

## Archiving Deleted Documents

For the problem of keeping the deleted documents, you have no option to achieve this with build-in features/mechanisms like *sharding* or *replication*. The only way to do it is to handle that case manually, e.g. holding a separate collection for deleted documents, and simply **move** documents to that collections instead of deleting them.

---

For your global problem of moving data you have the following two options:

## [Sharding](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjSqaHqn4XGAhWGCiwKHRpHAKs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.org%2Fmanual%2Fsharding&ei=0T14VZL9J4aVsAGajoHYCg&usg=AFQjCNGSeRs9E9W7vvXoe-CJbFbVgjh8Zg&sig2=8VrZ9dWpgPEM4GU6MANYXQ)

Using sharding you will split your data into pieces which will be stored on two (in your case) different servers. In this scenario you can use the [**`moveChunk`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/moveChunk/#dbcmd.moveChunk) method as you have mentioned. But this method is very tricky, as for that you will need to disable the built-in automatic balancer to have a full manual control over your chunks. Anyway, this is not recommended by the MongoDB:

> Only use the moveChunk in special circumstances such as preparing your sharded cluster for an initial ingestion of data, or a large bulk import operation. In most cases allow the balancer to create and balance chunks in sharded clusters

Besides this will only allow to split data, and finally, to get to your goal, you will end up with one full and one empty shard.

---

## [Replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/)

The replication approach is much more safe and easy to achieve. You can simply [configure a replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/) and add your second server to that set.

If the data is too big, you can [configure your second server as *hidden*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-a-hidden-replica-set-member/). So that no reads will be performed towards that server, so no inconsistent data will be received. After the data replication is finished, you will have the copy of your data on both servers.

As for using both servers as a single server, if you need to balance the requests between these tow, you can configure your [**`readPreference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) to [`secondary`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#secondary), which will assure that all the reads are being sent to the secondary server, and writes by default are done on the primary.

In this case your code will be unaware of what server you are querying. You will just run your client methods, and the rest will be done behind the drivers.

---

## Conclusion

So my advice would be to use the **replication** approach as more clean, pain-less and safe solution.